# How to create VM from managed disk using python Azure

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I need to create a Virtual machine from a volume in Azure using Python.Is there a solution to this

Answer (score 0):

You can easily attach a previously provisioned Managed Disk.

```
    vm = compute.virtual_machines.get(
        'my_resource_group',
        'my_vm'
    )
    managed_disk = compute_client.disks.get('my_resource_group', 'myDisk')
    vm.storage_profile.data_disks.append({
        'lun': 12, # You choose the value, depending of what is available for you
        'name': managed_disk.name,
        'create_option': DiskCreateOptionTypes.attach,
        'managed_disk': {
            'id': managed_disk.id
        }
    })
    async_update = compute_client.virtual_machines.create_or_update(
        'my_resource_group',
        vm.name,
        vm,
    )
    async_update.wait()
```

Please view this [link](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/wiki/Managed-Disk) for more details about Azure SDK for Python. Moreover, [Create and manage Windows VMs in Azure using Python](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/python)